# Looking for a manhwa about a healer from the church who awakens as a saint during a war, thus ending the war

Tags: story-identification, manga

The female lead is reincarnated as a child and she almost starves to death before someone from the church finds her. She picks her own name, but it's too complex and she has a hard time writing it. Her friend's name is Lilly, I think. I can't remember the female lead's name. Something like "Renae". She has brown hair. I remember her being out of shape while traveling during the war.

The female lead has a lot of holy power, and the male lead often goes to the church for help sleeping. She and Lily end up getting a summons to go to war. During the war she sees the black-haired male lead get hurt, freaks out and awakens as a saint. This ends up ending the war, mass healing everyone - including enemies.

Comment: Its called "a false confession "

Comment: Hi, welcome to SciFi.SE! When and where did you read this?

Comment: Could you post "A False Confession" as a self-answer so the system shows that the question has an answer?

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments, this is *[False Confession](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/false-confession)*.

> "I think I’ve fallen for you." With a single drunken confession, Renesha's plans to live a comfortable and uneventful life were shattered. Somehow she confessed her love to the wrong man: the Grim Reaper of the Battlefield, Duke Cavert Willard! It's the worst thing to happen to her since she woke up in this fantasy universe and discovered her divine powers. In the midst of a **war with a neighboring country, Renesha must balance her duties as a healer** with her feelings for two alluring knights. When romance blooms on the battlefield, who will be victorious in the battle for Renee's heart?

The main character's name is Renee; the friend's name is Lili.

Chapter 2 has a flashback that shows her as a starving child after reincarnating in another world.

[image]

She is then picked up by the church.

[image]